# Android: data not loading in fragmentstateviewpager while setting current page

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using fragmentstateviewpager where the fragments are created dynamically. Each page loads data by calling a web service. My viewpager will have 5 items, by default I am setting the current item as the 5th item using:

```
mPager.setCurrentItem(4);
```

The 5th item is getting displayed but data is not loaded in it. When I swipe two items back and comes again to the 5th item, now the data is loaded. Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Where you are displaying data in view pager like custom view, etc.

Comment: @SurenderKumar the page is consists of textviews and expandable listview. I am fetching data from server and displaying in these views.

Comment: Are you using fragment for that means the viewpager is inside an activtiy or inside a fragment because if it is a fragment than the problem will occur.

Comment: @SurenderKumar the view pager is inside an activity.

Comment: That's strange, can you show me some of your code?